# How to audit into different database (Hibernate/Envers)?

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate Envers to audit dataBase Change.
How to audit(Store) Hibernate Envers Audit Table into different DataBase?

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at the following configuration parameters

```
org.hibernate.envers.default_schema
org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog
```

Depending on whether your data uses schemas or catalogs, you'll want to configure one of these in order to influence where the audit schema objects should be stored.  These settings mirror the Hibernate ORM equivalent settings `org.hibernate.default_schema` and `org.hibernate.default_catalog` but is limited to the Envers audit schema objects only.

Comment: Thanks, @Naros I know this configuration but what I'm looking for is using different database